# TableViewCell Height automatically adjusted to screen size

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have already implemented a tableView with my content needed. There are only 5 cells to be displayed. What I can't achieve right now is the following:

I want the five cells to be distributed evenly over the height of the tableview, dependend on the iphone used. So logically there should be a bigger height for an iPhone 5 than for the iphone 4. Also if there is retina or no retina there should be the correct distribution of the cells.

Do I have to provide different background images for that?
and what would be the best approach for that:

the tableview looks like this:

[HEADER]
[A - TEXT 1]
[B - TEXT 2]
[C - TEXT 3]
[D - TEXT 4]
[E - TEXT 5]

There should be no scrolling be possible at the end of day. Just automatically evenly distributed cells.

I am so glad for help on that...

thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you can use the UITableViewDelegate method [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to simple return the tables height divided by 5, which will make each cell a fifth of the tables height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [tableView bounds].size.height / (CGFloat)[myDataSourceArray count];
}
```

This will work for both iPhone 5 and iPhone 4 provided that you have configured the table to be the size of the screen. Furthermore, there is nothing you need to do to set the cells up for retina/non retina considering that when programming for iOS you specify screen dimensions in points not pixels which allows iOS to handle scaling automatically.

Then about the background images, there are a couple of different ways to do this depending on what end results you want. For example, if you just want to fill the cell with a pattern image and let the default table view separator divided them you can make an image in the minimum dimensions required to achieve the pattern. (could be 2x2px and 4x4 @2x) Then simply use:

```
[[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPatternImage"]]];
```

Or if you have an image with some sort of border that you wish to display around the cell, you could use a resizable image with [cap insets](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) to draw around the border and then fill the inside of the cell with a pattern, here's a screenshot to help explain how it works:

[image]

And then of course you could just add a UIImageView as a subview of the cell and add the full image to it which isn't exactly *wrong*, but I wouldn't recommend it because the other two ways I've suggested are more efficient. Hope this helps!